# Firebase onCreate is confusing

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

This is the structure of my database:

```
[Database Name]
     - Users [Table Name]
        - Nathan
        - Kyle
        - Paul
```

I'm using the onCreate method of Firebase Functions which will called every time there is a new user that is created under the Users table which is what I have understood from:

- onCreate(), which triggers when new data is created in the Realtime Database.

This is my code in the firebase functions:

```
exports.testMatching = functions.database
  .ref('/Users')
  .onCreate(event => {
     console.log("Event data: ", event.data.val())
     return 0
  })
```

Now my problem is when the Users table is empty then I inserted a new data the onCreate is called but when the Users table is not empty then I inserted a new data, the onCreate is not called.

Is this how it should be?

Comment: maybe you can share us with your code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> `onCreate()`, which triggers when new data is created in the Realtime Database.

```
exports.pushnotification =functions.database.ref('/Users/{pushId}').onWrite((snapshot,context) => { 
  var original = snapshot.val(); 
});
```

If you have this database:

```
Users
  user1
    name: user1
    email: user1@gmail.com
  user2
    name: user2
    email: user2@gmail.com
```

You need to add a wildcard `{pushid}` so whenever you add data under an id, it will trigger.